# How to re-create layout with stretched text and two button-like views in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm re-writing my application written in Kotlin to Flutter, but I'm struggling to re-create layout shown in an image below.

Kotlin:
[image: Kotlin]

Flutter:
[image: Flutter]

I want the largest text to be stretched all the way downwards and I want to have two button-like Views with the given color, but I don't know how to re-create it. The text should be responsive, just like in my Kotlin layout, do when I open it on 18:9 screen, the text should be larger than on 16:9.

If there's someone, who can help me, I will be extremely glad!

Code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class GeneratedCouponScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text('DATA WYDANIA:', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
                      Text('10/09/2019', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black))
                    ],
                  ),
                  Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text('UNIKALNY KOD', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
                      Text('e-86-tC-9', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),)
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
              Column(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                  Image.asset('assets/images/coupon_hamburger.png'),
                  Text('blablafjafjjaffjafaafafjjfajjfjafafjajfafjajffjafjafjafjafjafjafjafjffjfjsigsuhgurghsrgshgrghwrughsrugsrhruighghgugrhgirghwruighgwruighwuighwgrigwrhugiwrughiwrugiwrghuwrughguhgrugrhiafaifafijaefioefaioeiofaijafji', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),)
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to wrap the text fields with Container and use the margin parameter. 
   e.g:

   > Container(child:Text('UNIKALNY KOD', 
   >   style: TextStyle(color:colors.black)),margin:EdgeInsets.only(top:10,bottom:10));
2. To equally spread the main Column elements use this parameter within:

   > mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly

Hope it helps.